# Installing CUDASW++3.0: nvcc not found

Tags: nvidia, compiling

I can't install CUDASW++3.0. The error message I get is:

```
asmaa@ubuntu:~/Documents/cudasw++v3.0.14$ make
mkdir -p objs
nvcc -O3 -arch  sm_30 --ptxas-options=-v -use_fast_math -Xcompiler -funroll-loops -Xcompiler -msse2  -DMAX_SEQ_LENGTH_THRESHOLD=3072 -I. -I ~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK//C/common/inc -c CFastaFile.cpp -o objs/CFastaFile.cpp.o
/bin/sh: 1: nvcc: not found
make: *** [objs/CFastaFile.cpp.o] Error 127
```

My GPU card is a GT 630M, fermi architecture.
What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message, it seems you are missing the `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` package.

To install `nvidia-cuda-toolkit`, do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

and then retry using `make`